# Creating Datatable as per user input from the database

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have two Primeface datatable with own panelGroup.
One is used to input from the user.
Second one is used to display data from the database.
Its depend on selectOneMenu option.

XHTML file :

```
<h:body>
<h:form id="form">
    <!-- Select One Menu For Invoice Data -->
    <br />
    <h3 align="center">Tax Invoice</h3>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="selectOne" value="#{invoiceBean.selectOneOption}"
        required="true">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Add New Invoice" itemLabel="Add New Invoice" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Old Invoice" itemLabel="Old Invoice" />
        <f:ajax render="groups" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <h:panelGroup id="groups">
        <h:panelGroup id="inputs"
            rendered="#{invoiceBean.selectOneOption == 'Add New Invoice'}">
            <table border="1" id="invoiceData">
                <tr>
                    <td> 1 </td>
                    <td> 2 </td>
                </tr>


            </table>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="outputs"
            rendered="#{invoiceBean.selectOneOption == 'Old Invoice'}">
            <p:panelGrid columns="3">
                <p:outputLabel value="Enter Invoice Number :" />
                <p:inputText id="inputInvoiceNumber"
                    value="#{invoiceBean.invoiceNumber}" />
                <p:commandButton value="Search" type="submit">
                    <f:ajax execute="inputInvoiceNumber" render="outputInvoiceNumber" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <br />
            <p:dataTable id="outputInvoiceNumber"
                value="#{invoiceBean.invoiceByContrId}" var="invoice">
                <p:column headerText="Invoice Id ">
                    <p:outputLabel value="#{invoice.id}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

Managed Bean Mothod :

```
public List<Invoice> getInvoiceByContrId() {
    invoiceDao = new InvoiceDao();
    invoices = new ArrayList<Invoice>();

    try {
        invoices = invoiceDao.getInvoiceId(invoiceNumber);
        if (null == invoices) {
            invoices = Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return invoices;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        invoices = Collections.emptyList();
        return invoices;
    }
}
```

InvoiceDao Class For Get Invoice Data :

```
public List<Invoice> getInvoiceId(String invoiceNumber) {

    List<Invoice> invoiceList = new ArrayList<Invoice>();
    try {
        startReadOperation();
        System.out.println("InvoiceDao.getIpsData()");
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM invoice where invoice_number = :invoiceNumber";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.setParameter("invoiceNumber", invoiceNumber);
        query.addEntity(Invoice.class);
        invoiceList = query.list();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        endOperation();
    }
    return invoiceList;
}
```

Now, I want data from invoice table as per invoice_number which entered by user as per requirement.

Error is :

```
javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @132,60 value="#{invoiceBean.invoiceByContrId}": Error reading 'invoiceByContrId' on type com.billing.managebeans.InvoiceBean
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:1002)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:629)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:762)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:744)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:258)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:220)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:84)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:304)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:399)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.billing.dao.AbstractDao.commit(AbstractDao.java:46)
at com.billing.dao.AbstractDao.endOperation(AbstractDao.java:60)
at com.billing.dao.InvoiceDao.getInvoiceId(InvoiceDao.java:108)
at com.billing.managebeans.InvoiceBean.getInvoiceByContrId(InvoiceBean.java:213)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor136.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
... 49 more
```

This is Error when I run code in Tomcat Server.
It Contain Null Pointer Exception error and Other also.

Comment: what is question here? you already have invoiceNumber of invoice bean binded with UI. you can have its value in bean. are you getting any error?

Comment: can you print stack trace here along with point where you are getting exception?

Comment: I think your getInvoiceByContrId method returns null at first time because invoice number is not updated yet. Try to return empty array list if you get null from DAO.

Comment: Thank You Boss, But another problem occur which is already in my error code.
    javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @132,60 value="#{invoiceBean.invoiceByContrId}": Error reading 'invoiceByContrId' on type com.billing.managebeans.InvoiceBean

Comment: what changes have you done in code? can you please update your post.

Comment: condition should be  if(null == invoices){
        invoices = Collections.emptyList();
    }

Comment: can you please try putting your code in try catch and checking if there any exception in calling dao class. How are you injecting your DAO?

Comment: try returning empty array list from catch block of your getInvoiceByContrId method.

Comment: But I enter those value which are already in invoice table but it will return empty list why ? 
Same problem.